# LDAPContext.search() returns empty result

Tags: java, ldap

Using LDAPContext class I search for a specific user and try to get whether it exists. But `search()` method returns an empty response.

```
private int checkUserOnLDAP() {

    String strLDAPServer = "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389";
    String strLDAPPricipal = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";
    String strPassword = "password";
    String strSearchBase = "ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com";
    String strUserToSearch = "riemann";

    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, strLDAPServer);
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, strLDAPPricipal);
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, strPassword);

    LdapContext ctxGC = null;
    try {
        ctxGC = new InitialLdapContext(environment, null);
        ctxGC.getAttributes("");
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.err.print("SEARCHER BLOCKED USER");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.print("SEARCHER WRONG PASSWORD");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    System.out.println("SEARCHER LOGIN SUCCESSFUL");

    System.out.println("NOW TRYING TO SEARCH");
    try {
        String searchFilter = "(&(objectClass=user)(sAMAccountName=" + strUserToSearch + "))";
        String returnedAtts[] = new String[0];
        SearchControls searchCtls = new SearchControls();
        searchCtls.setReturningAttributes(returnedAtts);
        searchCtls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        NamingEnumeration<?> answer = ctxGC.search(strSearchBase, searchFilter, searchCtls);

        if (answer.hasMoreElements()) {
            Object a = answer.nextElement();
            System.out.println("SUCCESFULLY, FOUND USER");
            return 0;
        } else {
            System.out.println("ANSWER HAS NO ELEMENTS");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("SEARCH FAILED");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

While testing, I use an online ldap service: http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/

Considering this online test service how can I check whether user exists?

Comment: I have founded a sample. it may helps to you : https://github.com/shardayyyy/ldap/blob/1d7ef92334c529b25f3cf4ecd5d1e90d8e2139dc/src/LDAPTest.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your search filter uses the `sAMAccountName` attribute, but that attribute is not available in the test server.  Use `uid` instead.

Comment: it seems my query can not find any user with given search filter. But it doesn't work both for "sAMAccountName" and "uid".

Comment: Looking at the server I find some documented entries are gone.  Especially the ou nodes are empty.  You'll find entries with a searchbase `dc=example,dc=com`, though.  That's why you always should use an LDAP Browser to check your results.

Comment: yes it works. with "dc=example,dc=com" as search base and "(&(objectClass=person)(uid=riemann))" for the filter. thanks.